# RecyclerView event when dataset is changed

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is there any possibility to handle event when recycler view data is changed? I am updating list in one part of the app and I call `notifyDataSetChanged`. In other part of the app where I have reference to the recycler view and adapter I want to handle this event.

Answer (score 2):

To get such an event you need to override the `onCurrentListChanged(previousList, currentList)` as below

```
val myAdapter = object : ListAdapter<Type> {
 override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<Type>, currentList: 
 MutableList<Type>) {
    ...
 }

  // other overrides
 }
```

By Lazy

```
private val myAdapter by lazy {
object : MyAdapter() {
    override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<Type>,  currentList: MutableList<Type>) {
        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Uknowledge_1 It would be great if you could accept the answer as it would help others also in the community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an `onCurrentListChanged(previousList, currentList)` callback that's invoked each time the RV's list changes. This callback is part of the `ListAdapter`. You can pass your own callback to the `ListAdapter` and then invoke it in overriden `onCurrentListChanged`.